# How to select rows with exactly 2 values in a column fast within a table that has 10 million records?

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table (TestFI) with the following data for instance

```
FIID   Email
---------
null a@a.com
1    a@a.com   
null b@b.com    
2    b@b.com    
3    c@c.com    
4    c@c.com    
5    c@c.com    
null d@d.com    
null d@d.com
```

and I need records that appear exactly twice AND have 1 row with FIID is null and one is not.  Such for the data above, only "a@a.com and b@b.com" fit the bill.

I was able to construct a multilevel query like so

```
    Select
FIID,
Email
from
TestFI
where
Email in
(
    Select
        Email
    from
    (
        Select
                Email
            from
                TestFI
            where
                Email in 
                (
                select
                    Email
                from
                    TestFI
                where
                    FIID is null or FIID is not null
                group by Email
                having 
                    count(Email) = 2
                )
                and
                FIID is null
    )as Temp1
    group by Email
    having count(Email) = 1
)
```

However, it took nearly 10 minutes to go through 10 million records. Is there a better way to do this? I know I must be doing some dumb things here.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your execution plan?

Comment: also: if email isn't indexed, index it!

Comment: Do you need **only** cases when for a given `Email` there is **one** row with FIID `NULL` and **one** row with FIID `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Yes, I think it's pretty clear. Can you do any processing in Java/C#/etc... or do you want everything to operate in SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try this query:

```
SELECT   EMail, MAX(FFID)
FROM     TestFI
GROUP BY EMail
HAVING   COUNT(*)=2 AND COUNT(FIID)=1
```

It will return the EMail column, and the non-null value of FFID. The other value of FFID is null.

Comment: If there was a coalesce, without an aggregate, it would have to appear in the group by clause, which would invalidate the counts.

Comment: @JustinDanielson - Not sure what you actually meant, but `COUNT(*)` **includes** `NULL`s, while `COUNT(<field name>)` **excludes** `NULL`s.

Comment: This will still scan the entire index but maybe performance is enough.

Comment: This solves the problem, but I don't think it is particularly performant.

Comment: Thanks @fthiella!!. Learned something today regards to count(column)! so much more concise and it took about 5 mins. Much better. I don't have control over the database, such I can't create an index on it, that's good enough for me! Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

With an index on `(email, fid)`, I would be tempted to try:

```
select  tnull.*, tnotnull.*
from testfi tnull join
     testfi tnotnull
     on tnull.email = tnotnull.email left outer join
     testfi tnothing
     on tnull.email = tnothing.email
where tnothing.email is null and
      tnull.fid is null and
      tnotnull.fid is not null;
```

Performance definitely depends on the database.  This will keep all the accesses within the index.  In some databases, an aggregation might be faster.  Performance also depends on the selectivity of the queries.  For instance, if there is one NULL record and you have the index `(fid, email)`, this should be much faster than an aggregation.

Comment: I'd really like to run this query with explain and see if it's doing everything on the fly, the group by is crushing the performance of these queries. What is the purpose of the tnothing table? I see tnull and tnotnull for getting FIID's of null and !null but what is tnothing for? if tnothing.email is null, then tnull.email is null, and then tnotnull.email is null as well. :[ Is it to prevent emails which appear in >2 rows? For example, if c@c.com had null,3,4,5 would it be accepted?

Comment: Would it ever be more efficient to simply run a select * orderby email and then write some simple program to scan through the result set and filter out the correct results? You'd just need a counter for sequential reads of the same email address, something to track if a null was found, and something to track if a numeric fiid was found. It would only require 1 scan and no temporary tables(this being the benefit). From the OPs query it's clear that the creation of temporary tables is killing the performance with all the added IOs. This comment is more for my own learning if you reply haha

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like ...

```
select
  a.FIID,
  a.Email

from
  TestFI a
  inner join TestFI b on (a.Email=b.Email)

where
  a.FIID is not null
  and b.FIID is null
;
```

And make sure Email and FIID are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

`I need records that appear exactly twice AND have 1 row with FIID is null and one is not`

## 1

On the innermost select, group by email having count = 2:

```
        select email, coalesce(fiid,-1) as AdjusteFIID from T
        group by email having count(email) =2
```

## 2

```
        select email, AdjustedFIID
        from
        (
          select email, coalesce(fiid,-1) as AdjusteFIID from T
        group by email having count(email) =2
        )  as X
        group by email
        having min(adjustedFIID) = -1 and max(adjustedFIID) > -1
```